# Changing subjects in a sentence: treated to, adsorbed with?

Tags: prepositions, transitivity

Can I change the first sentence to the following sentence?

1) The cells were treated with enzyme A.
->  The enzyme A was treated to the cells.

2) The protein was adsorbed to the nanoparticle.
-> The nanoparticle was adsorbed with the protein.

Comment: @Tory see my comment below re "adsorbed" and "absorbed"

Answer (score 9):

The original sentences are correct, you should use those.

"[treat to](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/treat)" means to give something as a gift or pay for something on someone else's behalf, e.g. *"I'll treat you to dinner tonight"*. So "The enzyme A was treated to the cells" makes it sound like someone bought enzyme A some cells as a present.

"[adsorb](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adsorb)" means "to cause a substance, usually a gas, to form a very thin layer on the surface of another substance". So *on*, *to* or *onto* are the prepositions you could use. "adsorbed with" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adsorbed+to%2Cadsorbed+on%2Cadsorbed+onto&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadsorbed%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadsorbed%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadsorbed%20onto%3B%2Cc0), the *most* common preposition after ***adsorbed*** is actually ***on***. But ***to*** sounds fine to me anyway (and I quite agree that ***with*** doesn't cut the mustard here).

Comment: Good spot, I'll edit my answer to include "on"

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'll raise your NGram with another [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adsorbed+to%2Cadsorbed+on%2Cadsorbed+onto%2Cabsorbed+by%2C+absorbed+into&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadsorbed%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadsorbed%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadsorbed%20onto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabsorbed%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cabsorbed%20into%3B%2Cc0), "absorbed by" and "absorbed into" for a passive voice.

Comment: @Tory: Good point. But I'll see your "passive" and raise you [an explicitly active voice](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=which+adsorbed+to%2Cwhich+adsorbed+on%2Cwhich+adsorbed+onto%2Cwhich+adsorbed+by&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhich%20adsorbed%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhich%20adsorbed%20on%3B%2Cc0) chart by searching for ***which** adsorbed xxx* - if I'm not mistaken, that should screen out all passive usages (which unsurprisingly tend to favour ***by***).

Comment: @Tory I think you've got "absorbed" and "adsorbed" confused :)

Comment: @D.Nelson Huh.  So I have.  Suggestion withdrawn.

Comment: I wonder if the OP even understands all those comments. Cards playing metaphors and other metaphors can be "above the pay grade" here.